# How to build on all agents in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to build a Jenkins declarative pipeline that will build on all agents in parallel.

How can I do this without disabling sandbox?

I have come across this page: https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/ but it seems repetitive, especially when padded out with my code as nearly all operations are performed almost the same on every node. Is there a way to do this and avoid repeating code?

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise, what you mean with _all_ agents in parallel? Usually you want to run on _any_ agent matching a label like `linux`, `windows` etc.

Comment: I have a different OS on each agent and I want to test all simultaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you follow the common pattern described in the referenced article.

By assigning labels identifying the node's operating system and allocating nodes based on these labels, you ensure that the job runs exactly once in each of the different build environments.

A severe drawback of your suggestion to build on all of the available agents (as said, I don't know anything how to actually do that)) would be in the case of one or multiple build agents being offline. So you don't run on Windows, because the server was just rebooting, but your build result is green as nothing failed? Not a good idea, isn't it?

Another benefit of the label-based approach is that you can easily add additional build agents to cope with increased number of builds, e.g., as your team grows. You don't want to build twice on Windows, when you add another build agent with Windows, right?

So I strongly recommend: Assign labels to your build agents and then specify, on which agents your job needs to run.

Comment: Thanks. I have been trying this. But the code doesn't seem right to me. I have to repeat the same code where I want to perform the same actions on each OS. That's a lot of repetition when you have ~8 agents and quite a complex build.

Comment: You have more power with scripted pipelines btw.

Comment: Thanks. Groovy noob, I'll give that a go.